# Type-safe way to call the methods of the instances of Activator.CreateInstance()?

Tags: c#

In the following code, `hs.Add(...)` cannot compile. Declare `hs` as `dynamic` should work but I'm trying not to use it. Is there a type-safe way?

```
void F(string colName, DbDataReader reader1, DbDataReader reader2)
{
    // .... loop reader1.Read(); reader2.Read()
    var x = reader1[colName];
    var type = x.GetType();
    var hs = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(type)); 
      // change var to dynamic will work. Trying not to use it.
    hs.Add(x); // Error
    // ...
    hs.Contains(reader2[colName]); // Error
```

I tried the following since the type of compile-time type of `x` is unknown.

```
var hs = (HashSet<object>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(type));
```

but it got error of

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
  'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32]' to type
  'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Object]'.
```

Comment: What's `paramX`? Why should `dynamic` work? Your question is very light on details. What have you tried so far? Are you keeping in mind that once you go the dynamic/reflection route, you are stuck doing _everything_ as untyped operations, until you either cast back to a type known at compile-time, or you compile new type-safe code to execute (e.g. using `Expression`)

Comment: Updated. `hs.Add(x)`. The question is about not using `dynamic`.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. As I already pointed out, if you want compile-time safety (i.e. type-safe), then you have to know the type at compile time. The `dynamic` type allows compilation to take place at run-time, which is one way to solve the problem. Building expression trees dynamically is another way to solve the problem (it's just another way to compile code at runtime). Basically any of the mechanisms that allow you compile code at runtime will work, other mechanisms will not. **What have you tried?**

Comment: Tip: Don't use the `var` keyword unless you're using anonymous types. `var` in C# is not the same thing as saying "I don't care what type this is" (for that use `Object`). By using `var` you're not able to immediate see what the static type of `x` is.

Comment: @Dai good advice for such questions... Also indeed type of `x` in the question is `Object` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're wanting to perform some kind of Set Operation (Intersection? Exclusion?) over scalar values. You can solve this problem using generics (and `DbDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>`) without needing to use reflection or `Activator`, like so:

If you intend to call this `F` function from call-sites where the type of the `colName` column is known statically (i.e. at compile time), then convert `F` to a generic method:

```
void F<T>( String colName, DbDataReader reader1, DbDataReader reader2 )
{
    Itn32 rdr1Idx = reader1.GetOrdinal( colName );
    Itn32 rdr2Idx = reader2.GetOrdinal( colName );

    HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>();

    while( reader1.Read() && reader2.Read() )
    {
        T value1 = reader1.GetFieldValue<T>( rdr1Idx );
        T value2 = reader2.GetFieldValue<T>( rdr2Idx );

        hashSet.Add( value1 );
        hashSet.Add( value2 );
        // etc - whatever logic you want here.
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
F<Int32>( "someIntegerColumn", rdr1, rdr2 );
F<float>( "someNumericColumn", rdr1, rdr2 );
// etc
```

If the Type being used can only be known at runtime (e.g. because of user-supplied SQL queries) then we'll have to use `Activator`, but can still use a `HashSet<>` indirectly by wrapping it in an adapter:

```
using System.Collections;

void F( String colName, DbDataReader reader1, DbDataReader reader2 )
{
    Itn32 rdr1Idx = reader1.GetOrdinal( colName );
    Itn32 rdr2Idx = reader2.GetOrdinal( colName );

    Type columnType1 = reader1.GetFieldType( rdr1Idx );
    Type columnType2 = reader2.GetFieldType( rdr2Idx );
    if( columnType1 != columnType2 ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Columns have different types." );

    var hashSet = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType( columnType1 ) );

    while( reader1.Read() && reader2.Read() )
    {
        Object value1 = reader1.GetValue( rdr1Idx );
        Object value2 = reader2.GetValue( rdr2Idx );

        hashSet.Add( value1 ); // HashSetAdapter will cast `Object value1` to its internal `T` type.
        hashSet.Add( value2 );
        // etc - whatever logic you want here.
    }
}

class HashSetAdapter<T> : IList<T> // TODO: Implement all of System.Collections.ICollection
{
    private readonly HashSet<T> hs;

    public HashSetAdapter()
    {
        this.hs = new HashSet<T>();
    }

    public void Add( Object value )
    {
        this.hs.Add( (T)value );
    }

    // TODO: Expose any other HashSet operations.
}
```

Comment: The Type being used can only be known at runtime. It seems `typeof(HashSetAdapter<T>).MakeGenericType(` will get error because of `T`?

Comment: @ca9163d9 sorry that was a typo at my end. I’ve fixed it.

Comment: `hashSet.Add( value1 )` has compiler error of `'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type`. Changing it to `IList` and `List` works.

Answer (score 1):

Like Peter pointed out, `Activator` is a method of working with reflection to dynamically create objects without knowing the type at build time.  Type "safety" in this method is though checking types or handle type conversion errors such as with `Convert.ChangeType`.

Note that DbDataReader has some helper functions to work with types such as GetFieldType and GetString which can be called instead using the column index.  For example:

```
int myColumn = 0;
var type = reader1.GetFieldType(myColumn);
if (type == typeof(string))
   string myValue = reader1.GetString(myColumn);
```

It more or less boils down to some using branching statements instead of reflection to manage your types.  Also, you should note that many ORMs like EntityFramework or Dapper, handle a lot of this type conversion for you.

Comment: The `type` from this answer + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method + the other answer's `F<T>` is likely OP's least type-unsafe bet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version using reflection.

```
var x = 1;

var type = x.GetType();
var hs = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(type));
// hs.Add(x); // Error
var method = hs.GetType().GetMethod("Add");

method.Invoke(hs, new object[] { x });
method.Invoke(hs, new object[] { x + 1 });
```

It's slower than `dynamic` if `.Invoke()` needs to be called millions of times.  `dynamic` seems need more time to setup.